# React - Extra table row printing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, conditional-rendering

I am looping through an array of objects, then based on a condition I am display that row in one Table or the other. However, when i call that condition, the object reacts how I would like (it displays in Table1) but in Table2 a number is being printed out also. The following is a snippit example. *files* contains and array of objects, *person*. If the person is *male*, they are added to an array and that array is passed to a seperate componenet and rendered elsewhere, This works. If the person is not male, they are returned in the table underneath the condiditon.

```
<tbody>
{props.files.map(person=> ( 
    <div>
        {(person.gender === "male") ? maleArray.push(person) :
            <tr>
                <td>{person.name}</td>
                <td>{person.age}</td>
            </tr>
         }
    </div>
))}
</tbody>
```

The problem is, everytime a male is detected, they are not displayed in the female table but a number is printed instead. For example,

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Mary | 51 |
| 1 |  |
| Jane | 19 |

The male table works as expected but if a male is detected in the loop, i get this output in the female table.

**EDIT:** Table is printing weird in final version. It would look something like this 
**Name**    **Age** 
Mary    51
1
Jane    19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSX you use ternary operator, it ALWAYS returns value when execution is finished, and that returned value is passed to a markup. So when a loop executes on "female" table, along with female names it shows the result of execution push method on an array in place of male names, which is an array length, that's why you see integers in a table. Try to separate male and female names in a component, not in JSX, and then there is no need to put a condition in JSX

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware it always returned a value. Separating components worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Map` performs an action on every element of the array and takes the return value.

`maleArray.push(person)` returns 1 if successfull, so 1 gets rendered instead of the values.

You could create a male- and a female-array inside a `forEach-loop` and map those arrays instead.

Comment: When another male is detected it will display 2, then 3 and so on, is this correct to your theory? Also, is it correct to use conditional rendering in the way I have used it, calling logic (maleArray.push(person)) instead of a component?

Comment: Okay, so push won't return 1 if successfull, but some kind of count. But basically, this is what I meant. 

No, that's your problem with the conditional rendering. You need to use something different - like forEach - here I guess.